# Nginx web page via browser i am unable to accessing

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat

Hi i have an issue with Nginx web page.

I am using Aws Amazon Linux 2 server i want to deploy react js frontend application on AWS ,i installed all prerequisites i e
Node js,npm packages, Nginx after completing configuration, when I hit with my 172.31.153.44:3000 (url),i am unable to access Web page, but when try with
curl 172.31.153.44:3000 in my terminal it's working fine.please help me y i am not accessing Nginx web page via browser

Comment: If the page is unencrypted, then you may have to specify http:// in your browser.

Comment: Check is 3000 port open in aws and linux firewall